# Insert a row in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

If I have a data frame

```
set.seed(12345) 
df=data.frame(a=rnorm(5),b=rnorm(5))
```

I can add a row by e.g.

`df[6,] =c(5,6)`

If I now do the equivalent in data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt=data.table(df)
dt[6,]=c(5,6)
```

It fails with an error. What is the right way to insert a row into a data.table?

Comment: I think an `insert()` function is planned for this package to make it relatively fast to add rows, but as of now, you have to preallocate the `nrow` of the data table. Maybe this: http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1458&group_id=240&atid=978

Comment: Is `rbind(dt,list(5,6))` sufficient for you purpose?

Comment: btw ime every time I thought I needed to add data row by row, I was thinking C-style and not R-style - so aside from the above comments you should reconsider whether or not you actually need to do this

Comment: I think this is almost the same question...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792001/add-a-row-by-reference-at-the-end-of-a-data-table-object

Comment: @Roland: most of the reason for using data.table is memory efficiency, due to not copying tables. Rbind *does* create copies, and can become a huge memory hog with big data...

Comment: @naught101 Please note that my comment is almost two years old. data.table has been improved in that time as has my understanding of it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To expand on @Franks answer, if in your particular case you are appending a row, it's :

```
set.seed(12345) 
dt1 <- data.table(a=rnorm(5), b=rnorm(5))
```

The following are equivalent; I find the first easier to read but the second faster:

```
microbenchmark(
  rbind(dt1, list(5, 6)),
  rbindlist(list(dt1, list(5, 6)))        
  )
```

As we can see:

```
                             expr     min      lq  median       uq     max
           rbind(dt1, list(5, 6)) 160.516 166.058 175.089 185.1470 457.735
 rbindlist(list(dt1, list(5, 6))) 130.137 134.037 140.605 149.6365 184.326
```

If you want to insert the row elsewhere, the following will work, but it's not pretty:

```
rbindlist(list(dt1[1:3, ], list(5, 6), dt1[4:5, ]))
```

or even

```
rbindlist(list(dt1[1:3, ], as.list(c(5, 6)), dt1[4:5, ]))
```

giving:

```
            a          b
1:  0.5855288 -1.8179560
2:  0.7094660  0.6300986
3: -0.1093033 -0.2761841
4:  5.0000000  6.0000000
5: -0.4534972 -0.2841597
6:  0.6058875 -0.9193220
```

If you are modifying a row in place (which is the preferred approach), you will need to define the size of the data.table in advance i.e.

```
dt1 <- data.table(a=rnorm(6), b=rnorm(6))
set(dt1, i=6L, j="a", value=5) # refer to column by name
set(dt1, i=6L, j=2L, value=6) # refer to column by number
```

Thanks @Boxuan, I have modified this answer to take account of your suggestion, which is a little faster and easier to read.

Comment: why don't use `rbindlist(list(dt1, list(5,6)))` as your second option for slightly better readability?

Comment: @Boxuan `rbindlist(list(dt1, list(c(5, 6))))` gives me `Error ... Item 2 has 1 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 2 columns...` See output from `list(c(5, 6))`, which is a list with one element vs. `as.list(c(5, 6))` which has two.

Comment: That's strange. I am able to run it on my machine. Maybe we have different versions? `packageVersion("data.table")` gives me `[1] '1.9.4'` and `getRversion()` gives me `[1] '3.2.0'`.

Comment: maybe this is the culprit: I am suggesting `list(5,6)` instead of `list(c(5, 6))`. =)

Comment: Yes; sorry, I missed that the first time. I agree with your helpful comments.