# Remove rows conditionally from a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with fields {id, menuitem, amount}.

This is transaction data - so, ids are unique, but menuitem repeats. Now, I want to remove all entries where `menuitem == 'coffee'`.

Also, want to delete all rows where `amount <= 0`;

What is the right way to do this in data.table?

I can use `data$menuitem!='coffee'` and then index int into data[] - but that is not necessarily efficient and does not take advantage of data.table.

Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In this scenario it is not so different than `data.frame`

```
data <- data[ menuitem != 'coffee' | amount > 0]
```

Delete/add row by reference it is to be implemented. You find more info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792001/add-a-row-by-reference-at-the-end-of-a-data-table-object)

Regarding speed:

1 You can benefit from keys by doing something like:

```
setkey(data, menuitem)
data <- data[!"coffee"]
```

which will be faster than `data <- data[ menuitem != 'coffee']`. However to apply the same filters you asked in the question you'll need a rolling join (I've finished my lunch break I can add something later :-)).

2 Even without key data.table is much faster for relatively big table (similar speed for handful amount of rows)

```
dt<-data.table(id=sample(letters,1000000,T),var=rnorm(1000000))
df<-data.frame(id=sample(letters,1000000,T),var=rnorm(1000000))
library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(dt[ id == "a"], df[ df$id == "a",])
Unit: milliseconds
               expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
      dt[id == "a"]  24.42193  25.74296  26.00996  26.35778  27.36355   100
 df[df$id == "a", ] 138.17500 146.46729 147.38646 149.06766 154.10051   100
```

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, in this case, does it take advantage of the keys to perform the comparisons `menuitem != 'coffee' | amount > 0` any faster than the typical data.frame?

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem Please see EDIT in the answer

Comment: Thank you much Michele. Also, the microbenchmark command is useful, thanks for posting it.

Comment: How would you use the ":="  or "<- NULL"? to remove the rows containing something by reference .

Comment: OK, I've found it's not yet implemented https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-data-table

Comment: I don't think this comparison is fair. Subsetting != removing rows. For instance: `microbenchmark(dt <- dt[ id == "a"], df <- df[ df$id == "a",])` show only x2 performance difference.

Comment: However OP wants to **remove** entries. Here we should use `!= "a"` for the example. And oh my, data.tables is 2 times slower here. 
`microbenchmark(dt <- dt[ id != "a"], df <- df[ df$id != "a",])` -- check it out. 

I am gonna go open an issue on their github repo.

Comment: ^ issue + explanation: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2890

Should be faster for large N

Comment: Can data.table rows be removed in place, without assigning to a new data.table? (Somewhat similar to the `:=` tool?)

Comment: Warning, this approach will also delete rows where menuitem is NA. See answer below.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
data <- data[ !(menuitem == 'coffee' | amount <= 0),]
```

Generally:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),b=c(4,2,3,1,5,3,4,7,6))
dt
#>    a b
#> 1: 1 4
#> 2: 1 2
#> 3: 1 3
#> 4: 2 1
#> 5: 2 5
#> 6: 2 3
#> 7: 3 4
#> 8: 3 7
#> 9: 3 6
dt[a!=1,]
#>    a b
#> 1: 2 1
#> 2: 2 5
#> 3: 2 3
#> 4: 3 4
#> 5: 3 7
#> 6: 3 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work but will also delete rows where menuitem is NA. If you want to keep these, you can "OR" that case in, eg:

data <- data[ ( (menuitem != 'coffee') | is.na(menuitem) )| amount > 0]