# Using set() to add a row to the end of a dataframe - R

Tags: r

I want to add a row to the end of the data frame in R, and I've read ([Add a row by reference at the end of a data.table object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792001/add-a-row-by-reference-at-the-end-of-a-data-table-object?noredirect=1&lq=1)) that the fastest way to do that is using set() from the sets package. But I was having trouble implementing it.

I have a character vector called names and I wanted to add it to the dataframe people. So I tried:

```
new_table<-set(names, people)
```

It runs, but then I can't view() new_table like how dataframes can usually be viewed. Any suggestions on how to use set correctly, or if there's another fast way to do it?

Comment: The **set** package appears to be based around a very specific data type, so if you want to deal with regular data frames, I'm not sure how that would be helpful, or why anyone would recommend it. `rbind` is the simplest way to add a row, but generally adding rows will not be efficient at any scale. Usually you're better off rethinking your approach further upstream.

Comment: It's function `data.table::set()` that is actually used in the linked answer

Comment: @HubertL Ah, I misunderstood, perhaps.

Comment: @joran OP misunderstood I guess

Comment: `data.table::set()` is not meant to add rows, just to modify them (like `:=`)

Comment: @HubertL Oh ok I understand now