# Adding a line with rbind changes the nature of columns in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am taking a data.table:

```
DT <- data.table(num=c(1,4,6,7,8,12,13, 15), let=rep(c("A","B"), each=4))
```

An then I have the following result:

```
> sapply(DT, class)
    num         let 
"numeric" "character"
```

Which is ok.

Then, adding a line:

```
DT<-rbind(DT, as.list(c(8, "B")))
```

And then:

```
> sapply(DT, class)
    num         let 
"character" "character"
```

I find this vicious that R changed the first column type to character and did not expect it ... I can change the column to numeric afterwards but it's painfull if I have to check after every insert.

Is there's a way to add line without this drawback?

Comment: Doing `rbind(dt, list(8,"B"))` is probably what you are looking for. (2nd comment to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652533/insert-a-row-in-a-data-table).

Comment: Exactly, I should have using simply `list` ... I took the way to add a line on this link actually! Thks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first problem stems from your use of `c`, the function to combine arguments into a vector. This produces an atomic vector (in this case - you are combining two length one atomic vectors, namely the vector `8` and the vector `"B"`) which may be of only one data type, so in your example `c(8,"B")` is evaluated first, resulting in:

```
str( c(8, "B") )
# chr [1:2] "8" "B"
```

Therefore you should not expect any other result!

Comment: Excellent answer to my mistake where I confused two data types in a structure which does only allow one ...

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel np. And +1 for Pascals comment above which shows you how to circumvent this. BTW to add say two rows you can use e.g. `rbind(dt, list( 8:9 , c( "A","B") ) )`.