# Inserting a row into a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I already referenced this question [Insert a row in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652533/insert-a-row-in-a-data-table) however, I am getting this error:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "All") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

When I try to insert a new row containing just the value `"All"` like this:

```
d <- copy(as.data.frame(Orange))
d <- rbind(d, c("All", "All", "All"))
```

It gives the warning and inserts `"All"` into the last 2 columns and inserts `NA` into the first column.

What am I doing wrong here, I know this should be very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I could get this to work without an error. I assume there is a better way to do this though.

```
d <- copy(as.data.frame(Orange))
add <- data.frame("All", "All", "All")
names(add) <- names(d)
d <- rbind(d, add)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `c("all", "all", "all")` to `list("all", "all", "all")`. Vectors (created by `c()`) create columns in dataframes. You can either do list or make the thing you're trying to `rbind` `data.frame` (since data.frames are just special lists).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/mvbutils/html/rbdf.html), the `rbind` arguments have to be either a data frame or an object that can be coerced into a data frame. It cannot coerce `c("All","All","All")` into a data frame. I would just create a new data frame instead: `d <- rbind(d, data.frame(...))`. You may also have some data type mis-matches going on too.

Comment: The code `d <- rbind(d, data.frame("All", "All", "All"))` results in `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names`. I think it is trying to take this and turn the "All"s into a single column instead of 1 "All" per column from the existing data.frame

Comment: Try specifying those data frame column names, eg. `rbind(d, data.frame(some.column="All",some.other.column="All",last.column="All"))`.

Answer (score 0):

For one additional way, you can add 1 to the row count of the dataframe and manually insert your values if you choose. It's not the most concise way, but you can mix and match data types.

```
  # Get the next row number
  row_number <- nrow(df)+1
  
  # Add a new row to a dataframe. You can refer to columns by name 
  # or by column number. 
  df[row_number,"today"] <- lubridate::today()
  df[row_number,"column_2"] <- "My value" 
  df[row_number,3] <- "My next value"
  df[row_number,4] <- "My third value"
```